# Java- Cannot resolve stopwatch class

Tags: java

I am trying to add a Stopwatch class to my code to measure the performance of my program.

Code:

```
 import java.lang.Object;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;


 StopWatch stopwatch = new StopWatch();
 stopwatch.start();
 stopwatch.stop();
 long timeTaken = stopwatch.getTime();
 System.out.println(timeTaken);
```

I don't know what I did wrong as I have imported the correct class as well and it just couldn't recognize Stopwatch.

Anyone can point out my mistake?

Comment: Which StopWatch do you use? Can you show the import statement? How do you do your dependency management?

Comment: I earlier used Google common base utility for stopwatch. You can initialise it like this : Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.createStarted(); I can add import statements if you want.

Comment: @AnarchoEnte What is the correct import class to use?

Comment: You are probably using `org.apache.commons.lang3.time.StopWatch`, which means you need to have the apache API - the JDK does not ship with this. *Edit: no you did not import any stopwatch class*

Comment: @Jai Isn't the API already pre-installed inside the IDE where we can just import it to use?

Comment: There is no StopWatch import statement. If you're using Apache Commons Stopwatch like Jai stated, you must add the library to your classpath and add the import.

Comment: @Daredevil you wrote the code. did you write a StopWatch class? is it in the same package? do you (try to) use one out of a library?

Comment: @Daredevil no, but you can manage dependencies per project, if you use maven (or similar)

Comment: @Stultuske I am trying to use one out of library , hence I;m asking if I import the correct one

Comment: @Daredevil without knowing which library ... we can only make estimated guesses. do you know how to import a library into your project or classpath?

Comment: Is this code in a method? Is the method in a class? Can you post something more like real code?

Comment: By the way, you don't need to import `java.lang.Object` or any other class in `java.lang`.  That package is imported implicitly.   And you should probably read the Java tutorial stream on Packages: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to import `org.apache.commons.lang3.time.StopWatch`. Assuming this is the one you actually need.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.StopWatch;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StopWatch stopwatch = new StopWatch();
        stopwatch.start();
        stopwatch.stop();
        long timeTaken = stopwatch.getTime();
        System.out.println(timeTaken);
    }
}
```

However the JDK does not ship with the `org.apache.commons.lang3` library. You will have to import it manually or via a dependency manager like `Gradle` or `Maven`.

Comment: where do i get the library in this case?

Comment: You can get the library from the Apache Commons download page: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

Comment: thanks it works now

Comment: @Daredevil You can always read the Javadoc from apache website.